# Как можно переписать поле depth сразу во всех объектах Layer в базе MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, prisma

У меня есть объект Layer c полем depth (глубина) вложенности. Работает это идентично z-index свойству css. При добавлении нового слоя я инкрементирую глубину. Мне необходимо при удалении какого либо слоя, переписывать глубину во всех остальных. А также у меня есть возможность перетаскивать слои друг на друга и таким образом менять их вложенность. В этом случае с клиента приходит новый массив с упорядоченным по новым индексам порядком слоев и их айдишниками. Как это все лучше переписать в базе MongoDB? В качестве провайдера я использую prisma.

```
model Layer {
  id            String      @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  project       Project     @relation(fields:[projectId], references:[id]) 
  projectId     String      @db.ObjectId @unique
  type          LayerType   @default(EMPTY)
  depth         Int
}
```